# Definite Integrals involving indeterminate quantities like log 0

Tags: calculus

I am reqired to evaluate 
$$\int_0^1 x\log x dx$$
I am getting 
$$\frac{x^2}2\log x-\frac{x^2}4$$
from $0$ to $1$ which means $$\frac12\log1-\frac14-0\log0-0 = \frac{-1}{4}-0\log0.$$
The answer in the book is $\frac{-1}4$. Can the second part containing $\log0$, which is indeterminate, be neglected?

Comment: Instead of getting $0 \log 0$, you should be evaluating the limit as $\delta \to 0$, for the lower limit of your integrand.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, if $f$ is not defined in $a$ but is defined on $(a,b]$, the integral
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx$$
is defined by the limit
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{a+\epsilon}^bf(x) dx,$$
if the limit exists.

You already calculated the indeterminate integral of $f$, so calculating $\int_{a+\epsilon}^bf(x) dx$ should be no problem. Then, just send $\epsilon\to 0$ and calculate the limit.

Comment: I tried it thus-

Comment: And, what did you get?

Comment: I tried it thus: (x^2/2*logx-x^2/4) from 0+a to 1= (1/2log1-1/4)-(a^2/2loga-a^2/4) as a approaches 0 = 0-1/4-log 0 - 0) again. How should I proceed further?

Comment: You are almost correct. What you must calculate is $$\lim_{a\to0} \frac{a^2}{2}\log a - \frac{a^2}{4}$$
Since you are learning generalized integrals, you must already know how to calculate this limit. If you do not, try to re-read the parts speaking about limits before learning on.

Comment: That is exactly where I am stuck up. How to find a^2/2*loga when a approaches 0?

Comment: Please do not consider my answer stuck up, I am trying to help, but I think you need to go back to basics. There is a reason why, when learning mathematics, you first learn how to calculate limits before going to derivatives and integrals. I can tell you the solution for this problem, but there is a larger problem ahead: You have no chance in the world of understanding analysis if you do not know how to calculate the limit.

Comment: @user133241 hint: Use L-Hospital rule.

Comment: I am stuck up, not your answer. I fully appreciate your help and I tried to get over this one but couldn't. Can you please give more tips on how to find it?

Comment: @5xum here it is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form

Comment: Quite right, I was in a bit of a hurry writing this. Still you can use the same rules. Sorry for the confusion. The hint is then:
$$a^2\log a = \frac{\log a}{a^{-2}}.$$
Now you have the form of $\lim_{a\to 0} \frac{f(a)}{g(a)}$ where $\lim_{a\to\infty}f(a) = \lim_{a\to\infty}g(a) = \infty$. There is a set of rules that helps you solve limits like this.

Comment: @user133241, if you don't know how to tackle that limit after *all* the hints you've been given then I don't think you stand a fair chance with integrals, leave alone improper ones. This is not an offence but just an observation from experience: you'd then need to go back to the basics.

Answer (score 1):

yours is an improper integral so find $$\lim_{h \to 0}\int_h^1 x\log x dx$$